# Can someone explain in layman terms what is Chrome's native client all about?

Tags: google-chrome

I read this article on arstechnica on Google's Native Client for Chrome, but I cannot understand what it is about. Can someone explain in layman terms what is the purpose of Chrome's Native Client?

http://arstechnica.com/web/news/2011/08/-native-client-enabled-in.ars

Answer (score 3):

In very simple words:

A web app written in say javascript is executed by the browser. The browser is in turn running in a sandbox on the OS on the Hardware

In case of the native client, the code runs in the sandbox directly instead of the browser, hence reducing one layer below it.
Because of this, the code execution will be faster

Note: This answer is not 100% accurate, but does explain the difference (or alteast most of it)

If the answer is wrong, please feel free to correct me

Answer (score 2):

native client allows some c or c++ software to be recompiled to run inside chrome - this means applications that will run in chrome arn't restricted to flash or java .

They also support accelerated graphics (you could run doom or quake in it ;p) and multithreading. While the software runs at near native speeds, and as a native application, its sandboxed, so if something does go wrong, or its not a legitimate application, it won't affect the OS.

In short, its a way to run 'regular' software in browser.